# What is the diference between Post Metadata and Queried Object

Tags: custom-post-types

When I edit a Submitted Essay post and look at the Post Metadata using the plugin JSM's Show Post Metadata. I cannot see `comment_status`.
But when I view the post using the Debug Bar and look at the WP Query > Queried Object I can see `comment_status ⇒ open`.

**Q1** - Is there a difference between these 2? - Post Metadata and Queried Object.

I am trying to set the default comment status on LearnDash Submitted Essays (post-type: `sfwd-essays`) to `open`.

My code below adds the Metadata `'comment_status', 'open'` (as an array, which might be wrong) upon the submission, and I can see that the metadata has been added.

```php
add_action('save_post', 'goldlms_sfwd_essays_comment_open', 10, 2);
function goldlms_sfwd_essays_comment_open($postID, $post)
{
  if (isset($post->post_type) && $post->post_type == 'sfwd-essays') {
    update_post_meta($post->ID, 'comment_status', 'open');
  }
}
```

Metadata result:
`comment_status`
`array ( 0 => 'open', )`

But when I view the post the Debug Query is still `comment_status ⇒ closed`

**Q2** - How do I set the default comment status for `sfwd-essays` post types to `open` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Q1** - Is there a difference between these 2? - Post Metadata and Queried Object.

Yes.

And I won't go into a detailed explanation (e.g. what a post metadata is), but these should help you for what you're trying to do:

1. Post metadata are saved in the [`wp_postmeta` table](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_postmeta). (Note though, the table prefix might be different in your case, but `wp_` is the default.)
2. The queried object in question refers to the post object/data which is retrieved from the [`wp_posts` table](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_posts/), which contains fields like `ID`, `post_type` and `comment_status` — the one you're trying to change.

So if you want to set the comment status of a post, there's no need to add a custom metadata to the post. Just use [`wp_update_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_post/).

> **Q2** - How do I set the default comment status for `sfwd-essays` post types to `open` ?

Not sure if there's a specific setting for that during post type registration, but there's a hook you can use: [`get_default_comment_status`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_default_comment_status/). For example for your post type:

```php
add_filter( 'get_default_comment_status', function ( $status, $post_type ) {
    // Set to open if post type = sfwd-essays
    return ( 'sfwd-essays' === $post_type ? 'open' : $status );
}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thank you Sally!